# Setting up oAuth Consent Screen

Tags: flutter, oauth, google-oauth, google-fit

Hello I am developing Flutter App that fetches the Steps from Google Fit Rest API but I am facing the problem in setting up the oAuth Contest Screen, I am developing a mobile app so what value should I enter for authorized domains. Can someone guide me here, please?

[Check the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ079.png)